# JavaFX TableView Edit with single click and auto insert row?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I used tableview in my program to display few rows it was good .
my program is used for accounting and as you know there is alot of data insertion in it and i used the table view and i faced a lot of problem :.

problem 1 : when the user want to modify a value he will double click to get edit the cell i want my user to select any row and start typing .

problem 2 : in my program the user may insert 100 row for a day of work i need a strategy to adding row automatically for example when he insert row it should add an empty row under the current row to complete his data entry easily .

please help me to solve these problems cause my user will enter a lot of data everyday .
thanks.

Comment: thanks very much @James_D it 's really good implementation i will try to combine it with my implementation to satisfy my needs .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example which

- enters edit mode as soon as you type on a focused cell
- creates a new row when you press enter in the last row (just as an example). Alternatively you can click a button to add a new row. In case you wish to use tab in the last row in order to create a new row, you'll have to change the code accordingly.

I'd advise against using empty rows because they show up in your model.

*InlineEditingWithDynamicRowAdding.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;

public class InlineEditingWithDynamicRowAdding extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Data> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Data(1.,5.),
                new Data(2.,6.),
                new Data(3.,7.),
                new Data(4.,8.)
        );

    private TableView<Data> table;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // create edtiable table
        table = new TableView<Data>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        // column 1 contains numbers
        TableColumn<Data, Number> number1Col = new TableColumn<>("Number 1");
        number1Col.setMinWidth(100);
        number1Col.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().number1Property());
        number1Col.setCellFactory( createNumberCellFactory());

        // column 2 contains numbers
        TableColumn<Data, Number> number2Col = new TableColumn<>("Number 2");
        number2Col.setMinWidth(100);
        number2Col.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> cellData.getValue().number2Property());
        number2Col.setCellFactory( createNumberCellFactory());

        // add columns & data to table
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll( number1Col, number2Col);




        // switch to edit mode on keypress
        // this must be KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED so that the key gets forwarded to the editing cell; it wouldn't be forwarded on KEY_RELEASED
        table.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
//                  event.consume(); // don't consume the event or else the values won't be updated;
                    return;
                }

                // switch to edit mode on keypress, but only if we aren't already in edit mode
                if( table.getEditingCell() == null) {
                    if( event.getCode().isLetterKey() || event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {  

                        TablePosition focusedCellPosition = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
                        table.edit(focusedCellPosition.getRow(), focusedCellPosition.getTableColumn());

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        table.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                if( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {


                    // move focus & selection
                    // we need to clear the current selection first or else the selection would be added to the current selection since we are in multi selection mode 
                    TablePosition pos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();

                    if (pos.getRow() == -1) {
                        table.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                    } 
                    // add new row when we are at the last row
                    else if (pos.getRow() == table.getItems().size() -1) {
                        addRow();
                    } 
                    // select next row, but same column as the current selection
                    else if (pos.getRow() < table.getItems().size() -1) {
                        table.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect( pos.getRow() + 1, pos.getTableColumn());
                    }


                }

            }
        });     

        // single cell selection mode
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        // add row index column as 1st column
        // -------------------------------------
        TableColumn<Data, Data> indexCol = new TableColumn<Data, Data>("#");

        indexCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Data, Data>, TableCell<Data, Data>>() {
            @Override public TableCell<Data, Data> call(TableColumn<Data, Data> param) {
                return new TableCell<Data, Data>() {
                    @Override protected void updateItem(Data item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (this.getTableRow() != null) {

                            int index = this.getTableRow().getIndex();

                            if( index < table.getItems().size()) {
                                int rowNum = index + 1;
                                setText( String.valueOf(rowNum));
                            } else {
                                setText("");
                            }

                        } else {
                            setText("");
                        }

                    }
                };
            }
        });

        table.getColumns().add( 0, indexCol); // number column is at index 0

        // allow multi selection
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // buttons
        // --------------------------------------------
        FlowPane buttonBar = new FlowPane();

        // add new row button
        Button addButton = new Button( "Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            addRow();
        });
        addButton.setFocusTraversable(false);// don't let it get the focus or else the table would lose it when we click the button and we's have to request the focus on the table in the event handler

        // remove selected rows button
        Button removeButton = new Button( "Remove");
        removeButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            removeSelectedRows();
        });
        removeButton.setFocusTraversable(false);// don't let it get the focus or else the table would lose it when we click the button and we's have to request the focus on the table in the event handler

        buttonBar.getChildren().addAll( addButton, removeButton);

        // add nodes to stage
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(table);
        root.setBottom(buttonBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800,600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


        // select first cell
        // TODO: why isn't this selecting the 1st cell in the index column?
        table.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    }

    /**
     * Insert a new default row to the table, select a cell of it and scroll to it. 
     */
    public void addRow() {

        // get current position
        TablePosition pos = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();

        // clear current selection
        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

        // create new record and add it to the model
        Data data = new Data(0d,0d);
        table.getItems().add( data);

        // get last row
        int row = table.getItems().size() - 1;
        table.getSelectionModel().select( row, pos.getTableColumn());

        // scroll to new row
        table.scrollTo( data);

    }

    /**
     * Remove all selected rows.
     */
    public void removeSelectedRows() {

        table.getItems().removeAll(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

        // table selects by index, so we have to clear the selection or else items with that index would be selected 
        table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();


    }

    /**
     * Number cell factory which converts strings to numbers and vice versa.
     * @return
     */
    private Callback<TableColumn<Data, Number>, TableCell<Data, Number>>  createNumberCellFactory() {

        Callback<TableColumn<Data, Number>, TableCell<Data, Number>> factory = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn( new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return Double.parseDouble(string);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return object.toString();
            }
        });

        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * Table data container
     */
    public static class Data {

        private final SimpleDoubleProperty number1;
        private final SimpleDoubleProperty number2;

        private Data( Double number1, Double number2) {
            this.number1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(number1);
            this.number2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty(number2);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty number1Property() {
            return this.number1;
        }

        public final double getNumber1() {
            return this.number1Property().get();
        }

        public final void setNumber1(final double number1) {
            this.number1Property().set(number1);
        }

        public final DoubleProperty number2Property() {
            return this.number2;
        }

        public final double getNumber2() {
            return this.number2Property().get();
        }

        public final void setNumber2(final double number2) {
            this.number2Property().set(number2);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

*application.css*

```
/* edit cell appearance */

/* If the padding is 0, then there's a grey area. If you set it to 2, then there won't be a great area.
 * However if you use a border color, then the border requires its size, so the padding is set to 2 - 1 = 1.
 * You have to toy around with the border. If necessary give it a width of 2 and make it the same color as the background color.
 */
.text-field-table-cell .text-field {
   -fx-padding: 1; 
   -fx-border-color:red; 
   -fx-border-width:1; 
   -fx-background-color:yellow;
 }
.table-cell:focused {
   -fx-padding: 0;
}

/* right-align the cell content in view mode */
.table-cell {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;
}
/* right-align the cell content in edit mode */
.text-field {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER-RIGHT;
}

/* colorize background only of rows which have data */
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.table-row-cell:empty .table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Roland really for this example it is very good for me at least but there is a problem when the number of rows exceeds the view 

 com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations for class javafx.scene.control.TableRow 

I don't know but it works and scroll to the last row

Comment: @Hassan Kbbewar: I know, I already created [a question and an issue at javafx jira](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714267/how-to-correctly-add-new-data-to-tableview-and-scroll-to-it) after I wrote the code for you. It works, but it's ugly nontheless.

Comment: @Roland Great work. How can we make the newly added row in edit mode right when it's added?

Comment: @Limited Atonement: Please create a question for that. I'm sure someone is eager to answer it.

Comment: @Roland My research uncovered that it's trivial: just `TableView.edit(newRow, column)` or whatever just after adding to the tableview. For some reason, it's not working in my application, so I guess I have some debugging to do to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: @Roland But here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497030 Although in my situation, it never works.

Comment: @Roland I have problem similar to this can you provide me solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598826/event-on-combox-which-inside-tableview-cell-javafx, I do many search for 2 weeks, but no avail, so can help me please