# Why do I get this weird warning when I scroll to the end of a ListView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, listview, scroll, javafx, warnings

```
list.getSelectionModel().select(game_ptr);
list.scrollTo(game_ptr);
```

When this code is run, I get the following warning:

```
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow addTrailingCells
INFO: index exceeds maxCellCount. Check size calculations for class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin$2
```

Now, the index in game_ptr is correct. This is tested. If I run the following code, there is no warning:

```
list.getSelectionModel().select(game_ptr);
//list.scrollTo(game_ptr);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly add new data to TableView and scroll to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714267/how-to-correctly-add-new-data-to-tableview-and-scroll-to-it). You can upvote the [ticket](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40564) opened for the issue

Comment: related?: https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/219

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a little bit late, but maybe It'll help someone.

In my case I had to set the Column Resize Policy to unconstrained-resize, that worked for me.